# In a nested MongoDB call, how do I ensure atomicity?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to atomically update/remove two documents in MongoDB by calling a new update/remove call from within the first update's callback? In the case below, I want to remove the second document from the collection, but only if the update to the first document succeeds:

```
db.collection.update(conditions1, {$set: set}, function (err,result){
    db.collection.remove(conditions2, function(err,doc_num){      
        db.close();
    )};
});
```

I'm coming across the $isolated query operator, but from what I understand in the documentation, this operator is used for performing a read/write lock on a single query which affects multiple documents, not on performing a read/write lock on one document after performing an update on another document through the first document update's callback, which is what I want to try and accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible because. As documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/write-operations-atomicity/) a lock would be aquired on a single query and not a whole transaction.

You can overcome atomicity problem by using [this](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/04/mongodb-multi-statement-transactions-yes-we-can/).

Answer (score 0):

As Amir said, it's not possible, but you can mimic the behavior in mongo by following the [two phase commit pattern](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). That link also links to how to perform rollback-like operations.